# How to send the class attribute to a component without the upper component having that class

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I recently changed carreer from backend to frontend developer and am now learning angularJs.

i have the following setup: I created a button component that returns a link or a button depending on the attributes given. I was wondering what would happen if I send through a class. This gives me some unwanted behaviour as the component gives it through but also holds it.

component:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .component('euButton',  {
        template: function ($element, $attrs) {
            if($attrs.click){
                return `
                <button onClick="${$attrs.click}" class="${$attrs.class}">
                    <ng-transclude>
                    </ng-transclude>
                </button> `
            }
            if($attrs.href){
                return `
                <a href="${$attrs.href}" class="${$attrs.class}">
                    <ng-transclude>
                    </ng-transclude>
                </a>`
            }
        },
        transclude: true,
        bindings: {
            click: '&',
            href: '@',
        }
    })

})();
```

I create my component as seen below:

```
<eu-button href="http://www.google.be" class="btn btn-default">Link example</eu-button>
<br>
<eu-button click="console.log('You have clicked me')" class="btn btn-default">Button example</eu-button>
```

the view as below is what I did expect, but not what I want to achieve. My button appears to hold 2 implementations of the same class and I do not want that to happen.

I use the bootstrap classes in this example. Ideally i would send through my own classes.

[image: Examples]

Any help on how to can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the template generation according to the attributes.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/768wg805/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log('You have clicked me')
    }
  })
  .directive('euButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      transclude: true,
      template: ['<a ng-if="isHref" href="{{href}}" class="{{class}}"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></a>',
        '<button ng-if="!isHref" ng-click="click()" class="{{class}}"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></button>'
      ].join(""),
      scope: {
        click: "&",
        href: "@",
        class: "@"
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (attr.href) {
          scope.isHref = true;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <eu-button href="http://www.google.be" class="btn btn-default error">Link example</eu-button>
    <br>
    <eu-button click="log()" class="btn btn-default">Button example</eu-button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you change your answer to component instead of directive? I'm trying to narrate my differences with your solution and the directive makes it more complex to me

Comment: You can not use the component in this case. Because the compile and link functions are unavailable. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component). As documentation say `When not to use Components:
for directives that rely on DOM manipulation, adding event listeners etc, because the compile and link functions are unavailable`

Comment: although i would like to see angular hold this option

Comment: If my solution solve your problem, please accept an answer as correct.